# Если слеш/косая делит не два слова, а более, пробелы ставятся (вокруг линейки)?

Tags: пунктуация, косая-черта

> Бар отеля расположен на последнем этаже с видом на Колизей из
>   бассейна, а с видом из-за столиков — на гигантское тело храма Четырех
>   Коронованных Мучеников/Santi Quattro Coronati.

Comment: А если не "выкручивать" фразу, а просто сказать: а из-за столиков открывается вид на ...? И зачем косая, если существуют скобки?

Comment: Впрочем,  "с видом на Колизей из бассейна" тоже не шедевр...Какой-то Колизей в бассейне.

Comment: Ну, из бассейна виднее! ))) Автора нельзя переделывать в себя!

Comment: И все-таки. (1) "Бар с видом из басссейна"(?!) Бассейн находится в баре? (2) "с видом на Колизей из бассейна" можно понять так, что у нас вид на некий "Колизей из бассейна".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно принято не отделять пробелами косую черту, если она разделяет два слова, и отделять пробелами с обеих сторон, если хотя бы с одной стороны от неё больше одного слова.

[Вот](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/should-i-write-module-theme-or-module-theme) вопрос об этом на *English Language & Usage*, сайте из того же сообщества, что и этот. RedDwight цитирует статью из английской Википедии и канадское руководство по письму и редактированию:

> There are usually no spaces either before or after a slash. Exceptions are in representing the start of a new line when quoting verse, or a new paragraph when quoting prose. The Chicago Manual of Style (at 6.112) also allows spaces when either of the separated items is a compound that itself includes a space: Our New Zealand / Western Australia trip. (Compare use of an en dash used to separate such compounds.) The Canadian Style: A Guide to Writing and Editing prescribes "No space before or after an oblique when used between individual words, letters or symbols; one space before and after the oblique when used between longer groups which contain internal spacing", giving the examples "n/a" and "Language and Society / Langue et société".

Часть из этого сформулирована по-русски в нашей [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0):

> При употреблении знака косой черты между одиночными словами его обычно не отбивают пробелами. Авторитетное «Чикагское руководство по стилю» (англ.) (в п. 6.104) указывает на возможность такой отбивки, когда одна из разделяемых им частей уже содержит пробел (Our New Zealand / Western Australia trip — наше путешествие по Австралии / Новой Зеландии).